# openssl ca command using libcrypto?

Tags: openssl

Is there a way to accomplish the following command using c api calls rather than a shell?

openssl ca -in ic.csr -out ic.crt -keyfile ca.key

It would be a lot more secure if I could do this process in-process rather than spawning a shell. I looked a the API for openssl and it wasn't clear how this could be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  The openssl itself uses the api to do this: http://cvs.openssl.org/fileview?f=openssl/apps/ca.c .

Basically, read in the CSR, do a series of `X509_REQ_get` calls to obtain attributes from the CSR, and use `X509_set` to set the attributes in the output certificate.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that file poking around the repository.  Maybe I can cut-and-paste some routines and embed them in my program.

Comment: I'd recommend http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL/OpenSSL-38/openssl/demos/x509/mkcert.c as an initial template.  Replace the hard-coded strings and public-key-generations with X509_REQ_get's and that should be most of what you need.  And of course, X509_sign should use the CA key.

Comment: Jumbogram, the snippet you suggested does create a certificate but doesn't seem to apply the CA signature.  Both scripts are pretty complicated and unfortunately uncommented.  It will take some time to reverse engineer what I need.

Comment: Set the issuer name appropriately (via X509_set_issuer_name; either hard code it or read/copy it from the issuer certificate).  Read in the CA public/private key and use that for X509_sign.